# Nontrivial solutions of equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Here, I have one problem in finding nontrivial solutions of a system of equations. I want to choose one variable, for example X1 and to get solutions of X2(X1) and X3(X1). It is not difficult when I have three unknowns, it can be solved by hand quickly, but if I have system with many unknowns, how can I find nontrivial solutions of a system with chosen unknown for example first X1 and to find others in function of X1. Here is a an example. I need X2(X1) and X3(X1)

```
 A={{A11, A12, A13}, {A21, A22, A23}, {A31, A32, A33}};
 X={{X1}, {X2}, {X3}};

Solve[(A-λ*IdentityMatrix[3]).X==0,{X2,X3}]
```

or with four unknowns I am looking for nontrivial solutions X2(X1),X3(X1),X4(X1)

```
 A={{A11, A12, A13,A14}, {A21, A22, A23, A24}, {A31, A32, A33, A34}};
 X={{X1}, {X2}, {X3}, {X4}};

Solve[(A-λ*IdentityMatrix[4]).X==0,{X2,X3,X4}]
```

Comment: `Solve[(A - \[Lambda]*IdentityMatrix[3]).X == 0, {X2, X3}, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> All]` ?

Comment: How about using [Eigensystem](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eigensystem.html)? `Eigensystem[A]`

Comment: ...if $\lambda$ is in fact an eigenvalue of your system, then you can use @Jens's suggestion and pick out an appropriate eigenvector that you can then normalize. If not, then you have a nonsingular system of linear equations, easily handled by `Solve[]`.

Comment: @Jens Eigensystem gave a large output. If I already have a lambda eigenvalues, how to get X2(lambda,X1) and X3(lambda,X1) directly? Solve doesn't work, Eigensystem gave a mess with root, I already have roots and..

Comment: Try to do it by hand and see if you can get a smaller answer, without knowing anything about the matrix coefficients and $\lambda$.

Comment: @Jens I understood your intentions. Here problem is Root[...] because I can not change it in output. So Eigensystem is very good command, but if I already know the eigenvalues lambda, can I get X2(X1,lambda) and X3(X1,lambda) automatically for X1=1?

Comment: Then you might be interested in `ToRadicals`, or the `Cubics`/`Quartics` option of the `Eigen*[]` functions. You might also want to look into `NullSpace[]`.

Comment: If you know lambda, then it is an eigenvalue of A. Let v be the the corresponding eigenvector, which is unique up to a constant multiple (under certain assumptions on A). If you want the first component of this to be 1, then you divide v by its first element and this is your x.